# Парсер не находит тег, который есть на странице

Tags: python, python-3.x, парсер, requests, beautiful-soup

Я пишу парсер на пайтоне. Столкнулся с проблемой, на странице есть тег `img` с классами `"gallery__slide___1n_To img__image___3j0lv"`, но когда паршу её, такого тега нет, мало того, пытался найти хоть какое-то изображение на странице, но в массиве `soup.find_all('img')` есть только 4 элемента, у которых атрибут `src` - это огромная каша из символов, это не картинки, я проверял). При этом если проверить код элемента картинки - то теги с такими классами есть.

Вот сайт: https://www.domofond.ru/dom-na-prodazhu-kurgan-2005637385, нужно достать фотографии дома с объявления.

Вот код:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

url = 'https://www.domofond.ru/dom-na-prodazhu-kurgan-2005637385'
session = requests.Session()
request = session.get(url)

page = requests.get(url)

soup = BeautifulSoup(page.text, 'html.parser')
images = soup.find_all('img', class_='gallery__slide___1n_To img__image___3j0lv')
print(images)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Данные при загрузке страницы находятся не в тегах, а скриптах, поэтому для их получения нужно или движок на `js` использовать (например, `selenium`), или извлечь и обработать через сам скрипт.

Добавил второй вариант. Для него через регулярку вытащил данные и распарсил их в `json`. Среди этих данных есть данные той галереи.

Пример:

```
import json
import re

import requests


rs = requests.get('https://www.domofond.ru/dom-na-prodazhu-kurgan-2005637385')
m = re.search('window.__INITIAL_DATA__ = (\{.+\})', rs.text)
if not m:
    # Добавить обработку в случае, если не удалось выцепить window.__INITIAL_DATA__
    ...

data_str = m.group(1)
data = json.loads(data_str)
print(data)
# {'itemsState': {'items': None, 'currentItem': None, 'currentItemError': None, 'similarItems': None, ...
```